# SQL PHP : How to select some column from sql database and display it in PHP/HTML generated table in descending order where condition is...

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sql table `res` which contains some rows and column. For example

```
Sno  RegNo        Name  sub1 sub2 sub3 total  percent  result  color

1    1DU12CS100   s1    10   10   10    30     50      fail    danger
2    1DU12CS101   s2    20   20   20    60     80      pass    success
3    1DU12CS102   s3    20   25   30    75     90      pass    success 
4    1DU12ME055   se    10   15   20    45     55      fail    danger
5    1DU12IS044   as    20   20   30    70     80      pass    success
6    1DU13CS077   sd    10   20   30    60     70      pass    success
7    1DU14CS111   df    15   15   15    45     55      fail    danger
8    1DU13ME006   fd    20   30   0     50     55      fail    danger
9    1DU11CV123   my    20   20   20    30     70      pass    success
10   1DU12CS444   yr    30   20   30    80     95      pass    success
```

When someone will enter `1DU12CS100` in form.html (GET Method), I want to display the result in php/html generated table order by `total` in descending order. The result should look like

```
Rank   Name   RegNo        Total   Percent  Result  
1      yr     1DU12CS444   80      95       pass
2      s3     1DU12CS102   75      90       pass
3      s2     1DU12CS101   60      80       pass
4      s1     1DU12CS100   30      50       fail
```

I want the table styled by bootstrap. If the result is pass then row should be green, if result is fail then row should be red...

`1DU12CS100` should first get substr( res.RegNo, 1, 7 )  .... [ I think ]

The form.html code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div id="wrap">
<form action="rank.php" class="form-horizontal" method="get">
 <fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="RegNo">Enter your Reg No :</label>  
  <div class="col-md-5">
  <input id="RegNo" name="RegNo" value="" class="form-control input-md" required type="text">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success">Get Rank</button>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

What should be code for rank.php ?

A realistic view can be seen from here http://www.fastvturesults.com/classranking/1nh13cs001/394154679

Comment: How about `SELECT <fields> FROM res WHERE RegNo = '<yourvalue>' ORDER BY total DESC'` ?

Comment: I only see `1DU12CS100` once in your table, yet your expected result contains 4 results, 3 with different `RegNo` values.

Comment: Definitely looks like one of those "what on Earth are you *actually* trying to achieve" questions...

Comment: How does `rank.php` looks like ?

Comment: What does rank mean ?
It shows the specified person is on which number. So all the people of that class is taken into consideration. 1DU12CS is contant for that class, only the roll number varies... Hence I substr the first 7 letter of string then find it in RegNo column and arrange in descending order of total...
1DU12CS100 - 1 is Region Code, DU is college code, 12 is year of admission, CS is branch, 100 is roll no...

Comment: SELECT RegNo FROM res WHERE RegNo = '1DU12CS100' ORDER BY 'total' DESC;
It is showing only one result.. But I want 1DU12CS100 is substr to 7 letter... 1DU12CS, then matching all the pattern should get arranged in descending order...@D4V1D

Comment: Well I don't know how rank.php looks like because I have not coded it and don't know how to code it. So any help in this regard would be highly appreciated ! @Alex

Answer (score 0):

Error checking and security aside, the basics are:

```
//get number from querystring
$regNo = $_GET['regNo'];

//get substring
$search  = substring($regNo,0,7);

//create query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `res` WHERE `RegNo` like '$search%' ORDER BY `Total` DESC";
```

Creating the html table is just a matter of looping the results and building the html.